# Include a PHP file in a Twig template

Tags: php, twig

I need to include a PHP script in my twig template. Is this possible?

Comment: I realise you can include another twig template in a twig template, but I need to include pure PHP.

Comment: The whole point of using a templating engine like twig is that you keep PHP away from the presentation. You do any processing before hand and pass the values to the twig template. Unless you can give an example where this cannot be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not want to do that.
What you can do is to create a twig extension and run your PHP code there. In your template you would just call your extension:

```
{{ myExtension() }}
```